# Library's sub-folder does not return any search results from sub-folder, top-level folder search however does?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search

I am the owner of a SharePoint library that works as expected. All contents of the library are indexed, and are found if searched from the top level-folder called "Documents".

The folder "Documents" contains a sub-folder called "Foo". The contents of "Foo" are found if searched from the top level-folder called "Documents".

However, no contents of "Foo" (not even file names) are found if searched from that folder's level, i.e. when the contents of the folder "Foo" are visible.

Why is that, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Please go to Library settings -> Advanced settings, set "Allow non-default views from this list to appear in search results?" as "Yes", then click Reindex Document Library.